# Coding a workaround for Android devices with no LED notification?

Tags: android, notifications

I have a Nexus-S which has no external notification LEDs to show a missed call, text message or email. What are some ways to implement a notifcation application? Write a service? write screen blanking application and draw on the app screen when blanked (what about locking?). I thought I would try turning on the hardware key back-lights as a notification but that proves to need root access so that's out. Please don't link to an app on the market unless it's Open Source. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are some ways to implement a notifcation application?

I do not know what a "notification application" is. To notify users (e.g., flash LED where available), use a `Notification`, with whatever mix of options you want on it (e.g., play a ringtone).

> Write a service?

A service can raise a `Notification`.

> write screen blanking application and draw on the app screen when blanked (what about locking?)

Users do not necessarily appreciate activities appearing out of nowhere. If you go this route, give them the option of a classic `Notification` or your activity.

Comment: what I mean by "notification application" is something which will run in the background, determine when the screen is blanked, and take some action to alert the user that there is a message or email waiting. The Nexus-S has no LED notification lights to do this so you have to pick up the phone and look often.  I mean to work around this somehow. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @wufoo: There are no documented and supported APIs for you to find out that "there is a message or email waiting".

Comment: hmmm.. Thanks. Any thoughts on where one might look? If I write a service to monitor messages/mails/etc that would be most of the battle.